# XSD - Re-use/inheritance of tags

Tags: xml, inheritance, xsd, jaxb, jaxb2

I have two tags which resemble some kind of boolean expression:

```
<complexType name="condition">
    <choice minOccurs="0">
        <element name="a" type="myns:condition-a"/>
        <element name="b" type="myns:condition-b"/>
    </choice>
</complexType>

<complexType name="condition-a">
    <all>
        <element name="value" type="string"/>
    </all>
</complexType>

<complexType name="condition-b">
    <all>
        <element name="value" type="string"/>
    </all>
</complexType>
```

I would like to combine these conditions with `and`, `or` and `not` constructions. Like this:

```
<condition>
    <and>
        <condition-a><value>X</value></condition-a>
        <condition-b><value>Y</value></condition-b>
        <not>
            <condition-a><value>Z</value></condition-a>
        </not>
    </and>
</condition>
```

Note that the `condition` tag is only used at the top, not inside `and`, `or` and `not`.

I came up with the following definitions:

```
<complexType name="condition">
    <choice minOccurs="0">
        <element name="a" type="myns:condition-a"/>
        <element name="b" type="myns:condition-b"/>
        <element name="and" type="myns:condition-and"/>
        <element name="or" type="myns:condition-or"/>
        <element name="not" type="myns:condition-not"/>
    </choice>
</complexType>

<complexType name="condition-a">
    <all>
        <element name="value" type="string"/>
    </all>
</complexType>

<complexType name="condition-b">
    <all>
        <element name="value" type="string"/>
    </all>
</complexType>

<complexType name="condition-and">
    <choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <element name="a" type="myns:condition-a"/>
        <element name="b" type="myns:condition-b"/>
        <element name="and" type="myns:condition-and"/>
        <element name="or" type="myns:condition-or"/>
        <element name="not" type="myns:condition-not"/>
    </choice>
</complexType>

<complexType name="condition-or">
    <choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <element name="a" type="myns:condition-a"/>
        <element name="b" type="myns:condition-b"/>
        <element name="and" type="myns:condition-and"/>
        <element name="or" type="myns:condition-or"/>
        <element name="not" type="myns:condition-not"/>
    </choice>
</complexType>

<complexType name="condition-not">
    <choice>
        <element name="a" type="myns:condition-a"/>
        <element name="b" type="myns:condition-b"/>
        <element name="and" type="myns:condition-and"/>
        <element name="or" type="myns:condition-or"/>
        <element name="not" type="myns:condition-not"/>
    </choice>
</complexType>
```

Although this works, it is not optimal. I am repeating the possible conditions in the `and`, `or` and `not` tags. As a side effect, the generated JAXB code is a mess.

Is there a more elegant approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of repeating the same choice multiple times XML Schema allows you to **create a global *xs:group*** (*xs:choice*, *xs:sequence* or *xs:all*) and reference it in other parts of your schema, just like global types and elements.

So you can use something like this:

```
<group name="anyCondition">
    <choice>
        <element name="a" type="myns:condition-a"/>
        <element name="b" type="myns:condition-b"/>
        <element name="and" type="myns:condition-and"/>
        <element name="or" type="myns:condition-or"/>
        <element name="not" type="myns:condition-not"/>
    </choice>
</group>

<complexType name="condition-and">
    <group ref="myns:anyCondition" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</complexType>

<complexType name="condition-or">
    <group ref="myns:anyCondition" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</complexType>

<complexType name="condition-not">
    <group ref="myns:anyCondition"/>
</complexType>
```